# Why i18n doesnt display the messages from the JSON file

Tags: jquery, html, internationalization

I'm trying to get new languages into my webApp for learning purposes, but I cant find any material that can help me within the internet, its pretty undocumented!.

I'm using i18n.js for this.

Currently I have this

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div id="text" class="col-sm-8 mx-auto">
      <h3>International Network Support & Service - Glas</h3>

      <div id="parrafo" data-i18n="description" style="white-space: pre-line "> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I did read that I need "data-i18n" to be a tag for it to load the message from the JSON file

Next I created this function:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$.i18n( { locale: 'en' } ); //this sets the languange
$.i18n().load( 'i18n/en.json').done( function() {  //this loads the json file

$('body').i18n('en');

});
</script>
```

and this is my json file:

```
{
     "en": {
       "description": "We oft arge enterprises in various business and IT environments."
           }
           ,
    "de": {
       "description": "penisWe offer prorises in various business and IT environments."
           }
}
```

But I cant get it to load!